# UltraISO error - DVD-R/RW media requires setting mode page to use DAO writing

Tags: windows

I've got this error which is connected to SATA running in AHCI. Yes, I googled and all that people said was to install Intel Matrix Storage Manager. Iirc, it's now changed with intel rapid storage technology which I installed and it changed nothing. Anyone possibly knows a solution to this problem? UltraISO 9.5.3.2901 (latest) Win 7 x64